# Proving injectivity of a tricky composite function

Tags: functions

I have a function $f$ $$(f \circ g \circ f)(x) = ( g\circ f)(x) + x  \ \ \ \forall x \in \mathbb R$$

I'm trying to prove that $f$ is injective, and I'm trying to evaluate $f(0)$.

What I've tried:

Let $g(x) = f (g(x) = \ h(x) = f \circ f \circ f(x).$

Then $h(x) = g(x) + x = f \circ g(x)$, but I don't know where to go from here.

As far as injectivity is concerned, I know that distinct inputs must produce distinct outputs, but I'm given nothing about the injectivity of $f \circ f \circ f$ or $f \circ f$.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Say $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, then we have $f(f(x_1)) = f(f(x_2))$ and $f(f(f(x_1))) = f(f(f(x_2)))$ so

$$x_1 = f(f(f(x_1))) -  f(f(x_1)) = f(f(f(x_2))) -  f(f(x_2)) = x_2$$

Say $a=f(0)$ and $b=f(a)$. Since we have $f(f(f(0))) = f(f(0))$ we have also $$f(f(a)) = f(a)$$ and $f(b) = b$. Now since f is injective and we have $$f(b)=b=f(a) \Longrightarrow a=b$$
So $$f(a)=b=a=f(0) \Longrightarrow a=0$$
So $f(0)=0$.